# Why doesn't this code raise a StopIteration exception?

Tags: python, iteration, stopiteration

In this code I have class name Iter that contains Two dunder methods `__iter__` and `__next__`. In `__iter__`method I set `self.current` equal to zero and return `self`. In next method I increase
`self.current += 1`. When it reaches 10 I want it to raise a `StopIteration` exception.

```
class Iter:
    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = 0
        return self
        
    def __next__(self):
        self.current += 1
        if self.current == 10:
            raise StopIteration
        
        return self.current
        
it = Iter()
for i in it:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `for`-loops handle `StopIteration`. If you want to propagate it further, use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) instead.

Comment: I believe StopIteration is just telling the for loop that it reached the end, and it should exit it. Changing it to `ValueError` (for example) does in fact show a traceback

Answer (score 4):

Your iterator already raises `StopIteration`, which is caught by the `for` loop in order to stop the iteration.  This is just how `for` loops work normally.

You can see this easily in your iterator if you add a `print`:

```
    def __next__(self):
        self.current += 1
        if self.current == 10:
            print("raising StopIteration")
            raise StopIteration
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
raising StopIteration
```

If you want to re-raise `StopIteration` after your iterator is exhausted, one option is just to raise one manually after the `for` loop:

```
it = Iter()
for i in it:
    print(i)
raise StopIteration
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
```

Another is to change the way you do the iteration so that the `StopIteration` isn't caught:

```
it = iter(Iter())
while True:
    print(next(it))
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(next(it))
  File "test.py", line 9, in __next__
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
```